# Запуск файлов .pyw двойным кликом в Windows 7

Tags: python-3.x

Нарисовалась мелкая, но противная трабла с запуском pyw-скрипта.
Я хочу чтобы он запускался как обычное windows-приложение.
Вначале скрипта пишу `#!C:\Python364\python`, было `#!/usr/bin/env python` - тоже не работает.
Python 3.6.4, PyQt5
Содержимое переменной PATH:

```
C:\Python364\Scripts\;C:\Python364\;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher\
```

Comment: По идеи, шебанг `#!...` строка работает для линукса/юникса, для винды нет (лучше добавлять их). Добавьте ассоциацию в винду для этого формата. Тыкаете двойным кликом и выбираете выбрать программу по умолчанию, там в диалоге указываете `python.exe` или `pythonw.exe`

Comment: ассоциация для pyw-файлов стоит программа "pythonw"

Comment: `pythonw` -- это запуск питона **без** консоли, поменяйте ассоциацию на `python`, либо переименуйте файл в `.py`

Comment: мне и нужно без консоли. Переименовал в .py, не запускается - ImportError: No module named PyQt5.QtWidgets

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python это для linux

Comment: В виндовс с рабочего стола 2 кликом запускается

Comment: PyQt5 вообще установлена?

Comment: да, установлена находиться здесь C:\Python364\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5, а запускаемый скрипт в D:\projects\bases\folder

Comment: А просто так, из консоли запускается? А питон один стоит?

Comment: из консоли запускается так: python file.pyw, просто file.pyw не запускается. Стоит еще Python 2.7, но не думаю что он мешает.